# oulook 2003 get all 'From' and 'To' email addresses

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

I tried this vba to get all Sender and Recipient email addresses from emails in Outlook 2003 folder

```
Sub GetALLEmailAddresses()

Dim objFolder As Folder
Set objFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

Dim dic As Dictionary
Dim strEmail As String
Dim strEmails As String

Dim objItem As MailItem
For Each objItem In objFolder.Items

    strEmail = objItem.SenderEmailAddress
'If Not dic.Exists(strEmail) Then
'strEmails = strEmails + strEmail + ";"
'dic.Add strEmail, ""
'End If

Next

Debug.Print strEmails
End Sub
```

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, the bits of code that actually do the collecting are commented out?! Look, if you want a serious answer, you'll have to give us a serious description of the problem.

Comment: sorry, I tried everything and copied commented out example. This new uncommented example is not working too

Comment: "Not working" how? Please don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example for To values

```
Sub ExtractEmail()
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim Email As String
Dim NS As NameSpace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
' Setup Namespace
Set NS = ThisOutlookSession.Session
' Display select folder dialog
Set Folder = NS.PickFolder
' Create Text File
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\email addresses.txt", True)
' loop to read email address from mail items.


Dim dic
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim strEmails As String

For Each Mailobject In Folder.Items
   Email = Mailobject.To

    If InStr(1, Email, "kovalovsky.com", vbTextCompare) Then
        If Not dic.Exists(Email) Then
            strEmails = strEmails + Email + vbCrLf
            dic.Add Email, ""
        End If
    End If
Next

a.WriteLine (strEmails)

Set OlApp = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
a.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My code I use in Outlook:

i use it to copy to clipboard but its one email only it doesnt work for whole inbox\folderofchoice

you might be able to create a loop to open your emails get the info then close the email etc etc...

```
Sub Get_SenderName()

 Dim myItem As Outlook.Inspector
 Dim objItem As Object
 Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject

 Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector

 If Not TypeName(myItem) = "Nothing" Then

   Set objItem = myItem.CurrentItem
   sSender = objItem.SenderName
   clipboard.SetText sSender
   clipboard.PutInClipboard

 Else
  ErrMsg = MsgBox("No Email Open To Get Data, Please Open Email To Use This.", vbInformation, "You Did It Wrong.")
 End If
End Sub
```